# Transfer a domain name hosted on Godaddy to Google DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, dns-hosting, godaddy

Our client has bought a domain name, let's call it `example.com`, with GoDaddy, but the infrastructure we're building is on Google Cloud.

1. Is it possible to transfer the domain to the Google DNS service? I'm
   not talking about binding the domain to an IP of a service hosted
   with GCP, but to actually transfer the domain name hosting. Thus having everything in one platform.
2. Does it actually make sense to do that?

The thing is that I haven't deployed a production environment yet (the project is in its early stages still), so we don't want to use the *main* domain name (`example.com`). For now I want to utilize only subdomains like `dev.api.example.com` and `staging.api.example.com`, but for that I first need to bind the *main* domain to some IP, and if it's not a production one, things will be messy since I'll have to remap it later again or not utilize subdomains.

I guess another option is to just spin up small instance for production env and host a simple, single static page website and bind this service's IP to the root domain.

I'm quite new to DNS and am not sure of the best practices and how to approach this scenario. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can transfer it to Google Domains, here is more information on [how to do that](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251236?hl=en)
2. It's up to you, technically you can have the domain with any registrar and use it with any cloud provider

For each subdomain (dev.api.example.com, staging.api.example.com , example.com - referred as just @) you will have a record that points to a particular IP or Host, you might point the naked domain record (example.com) to a simple html site that says app under development, coming soon or something of the sort until you are ready to point it to the production app ip. You might use [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) to host the static coming soon page